# GitLab CICD - Run stages only during merge_requests

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I want to enable a stage to be run during only merge_requests. But if I add `only - merge_requests` then the stages above such as build and test stage doesn't show up during the merge request build.

As you can see in this screenshot, the build and test stage are missing during merge_requests and only the stage `deploy review` is showing.

[image]

Any idea why Build and Test stage doesn't show during merge?

Here is the full cicd pipeline:

```
image: node

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy review
  - deploy staging
  - deploy production
  - production tests

build website:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sed -i "s/%%VERSION%%/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/g" ./public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./public
    
test website:
  stage: test
  script:
    - curl "http://localhost:9000" | tac | tac | grep -q "Gatsby"    

deploy review:
  stage: deploy review  
  only:    
    - merge_requests    # The build and test stage should still be visible but it isn't
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: http://test.surge.sh
    on_stop: stop review  
  script:
    - npm install -g surge
    - surge --project ./public --domain test.surge.sh
```

Comment: Can someone fix the screenshot? to be visible as inline

Comment: Are your build and test stages not already done when you pushed the commit to the branch? It doesn't make sense to rerun them in the MR again.

Comment: The MR stage requires the build folder which is called `./public`. Since build and test stage doesn't run, I get the error `./public` folder doesn't exists in MR stage.

Comment: During normal commits to branch example develop or feature branch it runs build, test and any other stages. But during MR it tries to run only `deploy review` without build and test